# How I can generate a `dict`, maybe `dict` inside `dict` of Django Model?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

**Hello Awesome People!**

I'm using `Celery` to run background tasks, but I can't have access to Model in celery tasks files, I want to convert these model instances to `dict`, so I can use them in template as Django has a perfect lookup way with `dict` like it was a model instance.

Such a simple question, for instance

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=123)
   the_future = ForeignKey('Country',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Class Country(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=123)
    img = FileField(upload_to='bathroom/')
```

I expect a `dict` like:

```
{
    'model_name':'ModelA',
    'id':1,
    'name':'Can you Dab?'
    'the_future':{
         'model_name':'Country',
         'id':'3',
         'name':'Despacito',
         'img':'/media/batchroom/teethbrush.jpg',
    },
}
```

Comment: With a `Serializer`.

Comment: Do I really need this for just a simple daemon email to send contents to users.?

Comment: well you can of course consruct a simple JSON encoder for these specific models, but typically you want to avoid encoding specific models/fields/... since if you later change the model, you need to change this functions as well.